# How to find the range of $1 / (1+x^2)^{1/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, elementary-functions

How to find the range of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$?

Ok. I've revised the (easy theory). I would like to complete the exercise finding the derivative of f(x) and setting equal to zero. I do it correctly, $$f'(x) = - x / (1+x^2)^{3/2}$$ but I don't have clear how to solve this equation once set equal to zero. I simplify the denominator but I don't know how to isolate the x.

Comment: the inverse, or the reciprocal ?

Comment: You asked for the inverses, and these can be computed. But the range can be computed without working out the inverses.

Comment: Ok! Better! So, in this case how to find the range? Taking the limits of the edges of the domain? In that case, since the domain of the function should be (-inf,+inf) we would have zero taking both limits at infinity. What else we need to know about the function in order to decide about the range?

Comment: @Always: Have you tried to draw just a crude sketch of the function?

Comment: solve the equation $$f'(x)=0$$

Comment: Well, I have asked a question about this, but without any answer :( maybe you could fill this gap http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509543/how-to-graph-elementary-functions

Comment: and yes, I know how the graph looks like because I put it in a graphic calculator but at an exam there is no calculator. I would like to learn doing by myself as much as possible

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, yes! thanks! I thought about taking the derivative and, actually, I did it! So, let me remember...I take the first derivative and I set it equal to zero and solve for x and I do this for getting what kind of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We try to rewrite $x$ in terms of $y$:
$$
0 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = y \le 1 \quad (x \in \mathbb{R})\Rightarrow \\
0 < \frac{1}{1+x^2} = y^2 \le 1 \Rightarrow \\
1 \le \frac{1}{y^2} = 1 + x^2 < \infty \Rightarrow \\
0 \le \frac{1-y^2}{y^2} = x^2 < \infty
$$
and get
$$
x = 
\pm \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y} \quad  (y \in (0,1])
$$
$y$ is not a function anymore, for every $y \in (0,1)$
there are two choices of $x$.

Here is an image:

[image: inverse]

Addendum: 
$$
0 \le x^2 \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow \\
1 \le 1 + x^2 \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{1+x^2} \le 1
$$
because $1+x^2 \ge 1$ thus $1+x^2 \ne 0$ we can divide both sides of the inequality by it, because $1+x^2 > 0$ the direction of the comparison operator did not change.

The RHS is $y^2$, so
$$
y^2 = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \le 1 \Rightarrow \\
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \le \sqrt{1} = 1
$$
This one holds because $\sqrt{.}$ is monotone: 
$$
x_1 \le x_2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{x_1} \le \sqrt{x_2}
$$

Addendum:

A criterion for local extrema is the vanishing of the first derivative:
$$
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \Rightarrow \\
y' = -\frac{1}{2\left(1+x^2\right)^{3/2}}(2x) = -\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$
This means
$$
0 = y' = -\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{3/2}} \Rightarrow x = 0
$$
Thus $y(0) = 1$ might be a local extremum. To know more we look at
the second derivative:
$$
y'' 
= 
-\frac{\left(1+x^2\right)^{3/2} 
- x \frac{3}{2}\left(1+x^2\right)^{1/2}(2x)}
{\left(1+x^2\right)^3}
=
-\frac{\left(1 - 2 x^2 \right) \left(1 + x^2\right)^{1/2}}
{\left(1+x^2\right)^3}
= \frac{2x^2 - 1}
{\left(1+x^2\right)^{5/2}}
$$
We see $y''(0) = -1 \ne$ so it is a local maximum.

[image: plus derivatives]

Comment: Thank you! But how do I know the first piece of information, namely y <= 1. You would answer: from the graph! Well, but I don't have this knowledge yet about graphing. Look at my comment at @Henning and also my comment at Dr. Sonnhard and at this question unanswered as well http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509543/how-to-graph-elementary-functions

Comment: does this tell something about y <=1? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: why 1 and not another bigger number? Sorry for my ignorance again.

Comment: Thank you...with the addendum I understand more, now. Could you tell me if we can determine the range using the derivative, as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner suggests, please?

Comment: This feels a bit overkill... :)

Comment: Yes, was bad enough.

Answer (score 4):

To find the range, since there is only one $x$ in the expression, you can simply proceed in steps:

- What is the range of $x^2$?
- What is, therefore, the range of $1+x^2$?
- What is, therefore, the range of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$?
- What is, therefore, the range of $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$?

It may help to sketch each of these functions crudely as you proceed.

Comment: well, I try to answer without checking anything. 1) [0,inf) 2) [1,inf) 3) [1,0) 4) the problem is that without the help of the graphing calculator, at the start of art of my knowledge, I am not sure if I could be able to answer to the last question. Thus, although useful your advice and appreciated, it is still not decisive in my case...

Comment: @Alwayslearning: How do you think the square root of something in $[1,\infty)$ would be in $[1,0)$? What does "$[1,0)$" even mean -- the left limit of an interval must be smaller than the right limit!

Comment: Well, if someone could provide an answer to this question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509543/how-to-graph-elementary-functions , I will learn something more about graphing and, as a consequence, about how to predict domains and ranges.

Comment: @Always: That doesn't really answer my question. What do you mean by $[1,0)$, and what makes you think the square root of a number $\ge 1$ will be a member of it?

Comment: I have answered like this because I thought that the parent graph of a square root is an half parabola reversed. Still, I thought the extremum 1 remains unchanged but what changes with the square root of x is that we would have an half parabola which points along the x axis as asymptote. This, probably wrongly if you say so, was the thought which motivated my choice about [1,0).

Comment: Ok, maybe I understand what you mean now. So, I would answer to 3) with (0,1]. I just got confused writing...

Comment: @Always: Why do you think the square root of a number greater than or equal to 1 would be between 0 and 1? Do you think, for example, that $\sqrt 4$ is in $(0,1]$?